# A word for "good state of the world"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

> Having multiple theories is not necessarily a ***good state of the world.***

(naively, one might have thought that abundance of theories is good; but in fact, multiple theories means it is not clear which one is appropriate for a given case)

Is there a single word or phrase that could replace the " good state of the world" in the sentence above?

Comment: In conversations, 'blessing' would often be the term chosen. 'Having multiple theories is not necessarily the best condition to be in.' is more formal.

Comment: If you found this in a publication or another source, could you please add that source?

Comment: *Having multiple theories is not necessarily **ideal***.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is, 'Having multiple theories is not necessarily desirable.'